Can't connect to AWS SQL Server from local machine using node
I have created a AWS RDS SQL Server database. I can access the same from SSMS. However, the same fails if I try to connect using Node JS.
Here is a snippet of the code.
const sql = require("mssql")

const sqlconfig = {
    user: "admin",
    password: "xxxxxxxxxx",
    database: "database-2.xxxxxxxx.eu-north-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
    server: "1433"
}

const connect = async () => {
    try{
        await sql.connect(sqlconfig)
        console.log('connected!')
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
}

connect()

The error message is something like this:

ConnectionError: Failed to connect to 1433:1433 - Could not connect (sequence)
code: ESOCKET

I have tried enabling TCP enabled in SQL Server Configuration Manager but with no luck.
Thanks in advance

Is the RDS database set to Publicly Accessible = Yes? Is it in a public subnet? Does the error happen immediately, or does it take a few seconds before it fails? What is the configuration of the Inbound Rules of the Security Group associated with the RDS database?

The error message is telling you the problem: it cannot connect to a server named 1433 on port 1433. Probably the server isn't actually named 1433, have you re-examined how you've defined the sqlconfig properties?
